# Qt Widget with slider

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm writing GUI application using PyQt4 and I need to create widgets and dialog windows which can be slided vertically. After clicking "Add new widgets" button (and moving it down) I create dynamically new small widgets (containing 2 `textEdit` objects). I want to avoid situation when window's height will be too small to properly show all widgets so the obvious solution seems to be a slider. I tried to use `QSlider` but I'm not sure if it's the best way and how to configure such slider.

```
class MyDialog(QDialog):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
    self.smallWidgets = list()

    self.resize(450,500)
    self.buttonPosition = 60

    firstWidget = SmallWidget(self)
    firstWidget.setGeometry(QRect(5,5, 450, 80))

    self.addWidgetButton = QPushButton(self)
    self.addWidgetButton.setText("Add new widget")
    self.addWidgetButton.setGeometry(QRect(165,self.buttonPosition,120,40))

    self.connect(self.addWidgetButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.addNewWidget)


  def addNewWidget(self):
    newWidget = SmallWidget(self)
    newWidget.setGeometry(QRect(5,self.buttonPosition, 450, 80))
    self.buttonPosition += 70

    newWidget.setVisible(True)
    self.smallWidgets.append(newWidget)
    self.addWidgetButton.setGeometry(QRect(165,self.buttonPosition,120,40))
```

[image]

Comment: Get rid of alll the `setGeometry` calls, and use layouts. Create a container widget for the rows of child widgets, and then add that to a [`QScrollArea`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I took @ekhumoro advice and implemented this using layout and `QScrollArea` (thanks! That's what I was looking for!). Scrolling works as I wanted, but I suppose my implementation is not the ideal solution. ;)

```
class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, strt, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.smallWidgets = list()
        self.setMinimumWidth(450)
        self.setMinimumHeight(600)

        self.setupLayout()
        self.setupScrollArea()
        self.addWidgetButton = QPushButton(self.containerWidget)
        self.addWidgetButton.setText("Add new widget")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.addWidgetButton)

        self.connect(self.addWidgetButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.addNewWidget)

    def setupLayout(self):
        self.containerWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.widgetHeight = 120
        self.containerWidget.setGeometry(QRect(0,0,450,self.widgetHeight))

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.containerWidget.setLayout(self.layout)

    def setupScrollArea(self):
        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scrollArea.setMaximumWidth(440)
        self.scrollArea.setMinimumHeight(600)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.containerWidget)

    def addNewWidget(self):
        newWidget = SmallWidget(self.containerWidget)
        widgetPosition = len(self.smallWidgets)
        self.layout.insertWidget(widgetPosition, newWidget)
        self.smallWidgets.append(newWidget)

        self.widgetHeight += 80
        self.containerWidget.resize(450,self.widgetHeight)
```